# How to add a line break to a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please can you tell how to add a line break to a string using JavaScript. I already use `<br/>` tag but it is not breaking the line. How can I achieve this?

**JavaScript**

```
var str="Click Here" +"<br>"+ "To Set" +"<br>"+ "TestSuite Name";
alert(str);
$("#testSuiteId").text(str);
```

**Expected output**

```
Click Here
To Set
TestSuite Name
```

**Actual output**

```
Click Here <br> To Set <br> TestSuite Name;
```

Comment: Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`, but take care to apply HTML escaping where needed.

Comment: @Jack Or you could use my solution and not have to worry :p

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Except that not all browsers honour "white-space: pre-wrap" :)

Comment: @Jack That's news to me... Could you provide an example?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You know which browser I speak of, the one whose name shall not be mentioned (older versions of course).

Comment: @Jack Oh. Well, since when do we care about people who disable Windows Update? If they're still using IE7, then they have deliberately made our lives difficult because Windows Update should have bumped them up to at least IE9 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = "Click Here" +"\n"+ "To Set" +"\n"+ "TestSuite Name";
$("#testSuiteId").text(str);
```

And in your CSS:

```css
#testSuiteId {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

More people need to know about this CSS feature ;)

Comment: @user2535959 Can you show an example of it not working?

Comment: @user2535959 You forgot to add jquery; [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ueysa/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.html()` in this context, since `.text()` would render the html string as a plain text

```
$("#testSuiteId").html(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you $("#testSuiteId") is textarea then use \n in place of 
 tag
and if $("#testSuiteId") is div then use .html in place of .text